# SQL JOIN omits some fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

`Product_T` with columns:
`ProductID`,
`ProductDescription`

`OrderLine_T` with columns:
`OrderID`,
`ProductID`,
`OrderedQuantity`

`Order_T` with columns:
`OrderID`,
`CustomerID`,

`Customer_T` with columns:
`CustomerID`,
`CustomerName`

I want to list the product ID and description, along with the customer ID and name for the customer who has bought the most of that product and also show the total quantity ordered by that customer.

I came up with following query, to list the max quantity product per order:

```
SELECT o1.OrderID, o1.ProductID, SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) AS A
FROM OrderLine_T o1
GROUP BY
  o1.ProductID,
  o1.OrderID
HAVING SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) = (
    SELECT MAX(s.d)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          o1.OrderID,
          o1.ProductID,
          SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) AS d
        FROM OrderLine_T o1
        GROUP BY
          o1.ProductID,
          o1.OrderID
    ) s
    WHERE o1.ProductID = s.ProductID
)
```

And that gave me a correct output of:

```
50  20  1
48  17  5
32  14  10
59  13  2
1   10  9
2   8   2
69  7   4
4   6   3
32  5   10
55  4   2
2   3   12
1   2   18
26  1   5
```

But then, when I tried joining it with other tables, so I could select `CustomerName` and `CustomerID`, like so:

```
SELECT
  o1.ProductID,
  s.CustomerName,
  s.CustomerID,
  SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) AS A
FROM OrderLine_T o1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      c1.CustomerName,
      c1.CustomerID,
      p1.ProductID
    FROM Product_T p1
    INNER JOIN OrderLine_T o3 ON p1.ProductID = o3.ProductID 
    INNER JOIN Order_T o2 ON o3.OrderID = o2.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Customer_T c1 ON o2.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID
) s ON s.ProductID = o1.ProductID
GROUP BY
  o1.ProductID,
  s.CustomerName,
  s.CustomerID
HAVING SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) = (
    SELECT MAX(s.d)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          o1.OrderID,
          o1.ProductID,
          SUM(o1.OrderedQuantity) AS d
        FROM OrderLine_T o1
        GROUP BY
          o1.ProductID,
          o1.OrderID
    ) s
    WHERE o1.ProductID = s.ProductID
) ;
```

The output shrunk to:

```
17  Contemporary Casuals    1   5
8   Home Furnishings        3   2
7   Eastern Furniture       4   4
10  Eastern Furniture       4   9
20  Dunkins Furniture       8   1
13  Ikards                  13  2
```

Why could that be?

Comment: Basic formatting and good use of whitespace doesn't go amiss. Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Please post your **full** `CREATE TABLE`  statements. Also, why do your table names have a `_T` suffix? You should not be using Systems Hungarian notation _at all_ (it's not the 1970s anymore), and especially not with database objects, because (and for example),Views and Base Tables are _meant_ to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should be using window functions here, such as `ROW_NUMBER`, along with conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  o.ProductID,
  p.Description,
  CustomerID = MAX(CASE WHEN o.rn = 1 THEN c.CustomerID END),
  CustomerName = MAX(CASE WHEN o.rn = 1 THEN c.CustomerName END),
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.rn = 1 THEN o.TotalQty END) AS QtyForTopCustomer
  SUM(o.TotalQty) AS TotalQty
FROM (
    SELECT
      o.ProductID,
      o.CustomerID,
      TotalQty = SUM(oi.OrderedQuantity),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oi.ProductId ORDER BY SUM(oi.OrderedQuantity) DESC)
    FROM OrderLine_T ol
    INNER JOIN Order_T o ON o.OrderID = ol.OrderID
    GROUP BY
      o.ProductID,
      o.CustomerID
) o
INNER JOIN Customer_T c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Product_T p ON p.ProductID = ol.ProductID
GROUP BY
  o.ProductID,
  p.Description;
```

If you *only* wanted the data for that one customer, you could remove the conditional aggregation and just filter by row-number

```sql
SELECT
  o.ProductID,
  p.Description,
  o.CustomerID,
  o.CustomerName,
  o.TotalQty
FROM (
    SELECT
      p.ProductID,
      p.Description,
      o.CustomerID,
      TotalQty = SUM(oi.OrderedQuantity),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oi.ProductId ORDER BY SUM(oi.OrderedQuantity) DESC)
    FROM OrderLine_T ol
    INNER JOIN Order_T o ON o.OrderID = ol.OrderID
    GROUP BY
      p.ProductID,
      p.Description,
      o.CustomerID
) o
INNER JOIN Customer_T c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Product_T p ON p.ProductID = ol.ProductID
WHERE o.rn = 1;
```